# Flutter shared preference -- Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

shared preference plug-in (shared_preferences: ^2.0.6)

It got an init instance error,Here's the error stack trace:

```
aunching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
package:travel_app/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           22.3s
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:59168/kc8UwLPVK5s=/ws
flutter: start
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:142
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:148
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:331
#3      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:358
#4      MethodChannelSharedPreferencesStore.getAll
package:shared_preferences_platform_interface/method_channel_shared_preferences.dart:44
#5      SharedPreferences._getSharedPreferencesMap
package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart:180
#6      SharedPreferences.getInstance
package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart:56
#7      Global.init
package:travel_app/common/Global.dart:36
#8      main
package:travel_app/main.dart:13
#9      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (d<…>
```

heres the my code (main.dart):

```
Future<void> main() async => await Global.init().then((e) => runApp(MyApp()));
```

Global.dart

```
static Future init() async {
print("start");
final SharedPreferences prefs = await 
SharedPreferences.getInstance();
print("_prefs $prefs");
}
```

The source code locator error is these:(method_channel_shared_preferences.dart)

```
await _kChannel.invokeMapMethod<String, Object>('getAll');
```

*Exception has occurred.
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)*

otherwise,The system I use is a MacOS,Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` before initializing

Answer (score 2):

Any one who are using **get_it** package and having similar issue, here is the most simple solution.
just add  **WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();** at the top of main function.

**Change your main function like this :**

```
Future<void> main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await di.init()
runApp(MyApp());}
```